# How to translate the menu title?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, navigation

Currently I am working on a multilingual website and have already a multilingual set-up.
Now I have translated menu items and it is working great, however I also want the menu title to be translated.

This is how I get the menu titles:

```
$menuInfo = menu_load('menu-second-menu');
```

and I get the title through by $menuInfo['title'];

I print the links with the following code (and the title is displayed above):

```
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => $menuInfo['menu_name'], 'class' => array('links', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => array('text' => $menuInfo['title'], 'level' => 'h3')));
```

So the links are translated, but the $menuInfo['title'] not and $menuInfo does not contain any translated information.

Any help?

**Edit:** The issue is I do not know how to get the translated menu title (programmatically) I made in Structure -> Menus -> Second Menu -> click the tab Translate and gave a different Menu title for the different languages. I am using the **Menu Translation** (sub)module of the **i18n Internationalization** module.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could come up with, to translate the menu title is by using the following:

```
$menu = menu_load('main-menu');
$menu_title = i18n_string_translate('menu:menu:main-menu:title', $menu['title']);
$menu_desc = i18n_string_translate('menu:menu:main-menu:description', $menu['description']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable `locale` and `Translation` module, goto `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` select the language and enter the corresponding English statement, then translate it.

Comment: These modules are already enabled. The point is I do not know how to get the translated menu title I made in Structure -> Menus -> Second Menu, than click the tab Translate and gave a different Menu title for the different languages.

Comment: did you search the original phrase?

Comment: I have searched yes, I found another thread discussing how to get the menu title using the menu_load('menu-name'); function, but apparently the Internationalization module doesn't hook into this one.